# Xamaring bindinglib project renames variable wrong

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a problem in a binding lib. project, using Xamarin 4.6 in VC 2017.

In an .aar project I have following code:

```
public static final class ConformImage {
public static final int DO_NOT_CONFORM_IMAGE = 0;
public static final int CONFORM_IMAGE = 1;

    public ConformImage() {
    }
 }
```

Xamarin creats:

```
public sealed partial class ConformImage : global::Java.Lang.Object {

[Register ("CONFORM_IMAGE")]
public const int ConformImage = (int) 1;
...
```

The compiler is arguing that a Member is called like the class, "ConformImage". 
In my opinion xamarin renamed it wrong and created that problem.

Maybe anyone has an idea about that and could help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `C#` normalization of the Java names, clashing in the names can occur and can be fixed via an entry in the `Metadata.xml` file in your `Xamarin.Android` binding project.

Either rename the class or rename the const, your choice:

#### Rename the class:

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='your.java.package.name.here']/class[@name='ConformImage']" 
    name="managedName">ConformImageEx</attr>
```

#### Rename the const(s):

```
<attr path="/api/package[@name='your.java.package.name.here']/class[@name='ConformImage']/field[@name='DO_NOT_CONFORM_IMAGE']" name="managedName"> DoNotConformThisImage </attr>
<attr path="/api/package[@name='your.java.package.name.here']/class[@name='ConformImage']/field[@name='CONFORM_IMAGE']" name="managedName">ConformThisImage </attr>
```

re: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/customizing-bindings/

re: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: Thats it. renaming the consts in that way worked. 
Thank you